# Creating a stockchecker using BS4 in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I open this link using webdriver
https://www.alternate.be/Grafische-kaarten?s=default&pr1=0&pr2=6655&filter_2203=NVIDIA+GeForce+RTX+3060+Ti.

Then I searched for the tag "Op voorraad" in the page_source but I don't find it. How can I find the correct element?

Comment: It seems that you can't find it because it's not there

Comment: I know, but when I use inspect element I can find the element.

Answer (score 0):

This site uses client side rendering. Use something like [selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) before using beautifulsoup to fill in the information

Answer (score 0):

You can scrape this website using [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) web scraping library without the need to use `selenium`, it will be much faster than launching the whole browser.

To get the required data, you need to get a [`.class` selector`](https://serpapi.com/blog/web-scraping-with-css-selectors-using-python/#class_selector) which contains the data we need. Think of the container as [matryoshka doll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matryoshka_doll) if it makes more sense.

In other words, we need to find a CSS selector inside which there's data about the price, availability, and title are located, in our case, it is `.boxCounter` selector.

To easily find a selector, you can use [SelectorGadget](https://selectorgadget.com/) Chrome extension that allows you to pick selectors by clicking on the desired element in the browser and returning it. It does not always work perfectly if the page heavily uses JS (in this case it works normally).

[Check code in online IDE using Beautifulsoup](https://replit.com/@denisskopa/creating-stockchecker-using-bs4-python#main.py).

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, json, lxml

html = requests.get("https://www.alternate.be/Grafische-kaarten?s=default&pr1=0&pr2=6655&filter_2203=NVIDIA+GeForce+RTX+3060+Ti", timeout=30)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "lxml") 

data = []

# iterating over every container (listing) and extracting data from individual listing
for result in soup.select(".boxCounter"):
  availability = result.select_one(".text-right .font-weight-bold").text
  price = result.select_one(".price").text
  title = result.select_one("#listing .font-weight-bold").text
  data.append({
    "availability" : availability,
    "price" : price,
    "title" : title
  })
print(json.dumps(data, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
```

Example output

```
[
  {
    "availability": "Op voorraad",
    "price": "€ 599,00",
    "title": "GIGABYTE AORUSGeForce RTX 3060 Ti ELITE grafische kaart"
  },
  {
    "availability": "Op voorraad",
    "price": "€ 539,00",
    "title": "MSIGeForce RTX 3060 Ti VENTUS 2X 8G V1 grafische kaart"
  },
  {
    "availability": "Op voorraad",
    "price": "€ 549,00",
    "title": "GIGABYTEGeForce RTX 3060 Ti Eagle OC 8G grafische kaart"
  },
  {
    "availability": "Op voorraad",
    "price": "€ 569,00",
    "title": "GIGABYTEGeForce RTX 3060 Ti VISION OC 8G grafische kaart"
  },
  {
    "availability": "Op voorraad",
    "price": "€ 649,00",
    "title": "MSIGeForce RTX 3060 Ti GAMING Z TRIO grafische kaart"
  },
  {
    "availability": "Niet op voorraad, geen informatie beschikbaar",
    "price": "€ 599,00",
    "title": "ASUSGeForce RTX 3060 Ti TUF GAMING OC V2 grafische kaart"
  },
  # ...
]
```